# Spring mvc controller mapping with and without slash

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a mapping in context.xml as follows -

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/test" view-name="/myview" />
```

Now, I also want to ensure that `/test/` ( with slash) also goes to `/myview` . But i do not want to add another `mvc:view-controller` mapping

Is there any cleaner way to support URL's with and without slash in mvc:view-controller mappings ?

Comment: Have you tried that URL with your current mapping?

Comment: Yes, it does not work. No mapping found exception.

Comment: Add the slash and see if it works without. (There's some magic that happens for normal controllers, but I don't use the direct view mapping myself.)

Comment: If i add / , then it does not work for one without /

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by adding trailing slash and wildcards  -

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/test/**" view-name="/myview" />
```

Comment: It will match every other path starting with `/test`. Not a very clean solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `URLRewriteFilter` in Spring.

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
         <note>Remove trailing slash</note>
         <from>/**/</from>
         <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```